# Drupal 7. Почему в мультиязычном сайте не открывается robots.txt из корня

Tags: drupal, robots.txt

site.ru/robots.txt - 404 not found

site.ru/ru/robots.txt - открывается

поясняю вопрос:
сайт на друпал-7 мультиязычный через модули Internationalization (i18n)

2 языка: русский и английский, русский по умолчанию,
все системные ссылки и выведенные через l() выглядят как

яндекс-вебмастер сказал, что не видит на сайте файлик robots.txt,
я ему не поверил, посмотрел site.ru/robots.txt и правда нжинкс говорит 404 Not Found,
но файлик в корне есть

зато файлик открывается по адресам:
site.ru/ru/robots.txt
site.ru/en/robots.txt

модуль robotstxt не помог..
site.ru/robots.txt не открывается..

Comment: где расположен указываемый файл? как настроены маршруты?

Comment: пояснил в тексте

Comment: @masdzen, вероятно, и конфигурация веб-сервера не помешает.